# Mege multiple array object into single array object based on key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, key

I have an array of objects of the structure coming from server response of iterated array object like as sample

```
var arrObj1  = [
    {"id":"1","value":21, "value1":13},
    {"id":"2","value":21, "value1":13 },
    ......n
    ]; 

var arrObj2 = [
    {"id":"1","value3":21, "value14":13},
    {"id":"2","value3":21, "value4":13 },
    ......n
    ]; 

var arrObj3 = [
    {"id":"1","value5":21, "value6":13},
    {"id":"2","value5":21, "value6":13 },
    ......n
    ];
```

But now I want to append the array values inot single new array according to key following structure of as iterated values of above array Expected Output:

```
var finalObj = [
        {
            "id" :  1
            "value" : 21,
            "value1" : 13,
            "value3" : 21,
            "value4" : 13,
            "value5" : 21,
            "value6" : 13,
        },
        {
            "id" :  2
            "value" : 21,
            "value1" : 13,
            "value3" : 21,
            "value4" : 13,
            "value5" : 21,
            "value6" : 13,
        },
        .....n

];
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOerflow. Could you provide some more information about what you have tried already? What did not work? What error messages did you encounter?  I am asking because it currently seems like you want others to do the coding work for you, which is not really the purpose of StackOverflow :)

Comment: Look away to [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: @NikitaMadeev flatmap is enough

Comment: Familiarize yourself with [how to access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/4642212) and use the available [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Methods_of_the_Object_constructor) and [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods) methods.

Comment: i tried using concat()  but it seem not getting expected output

Comment: @PrinceShukla please check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Push you arrays to a new array (you have to have your sub arrays in other list to loop through them) and then use flat, after that group your object according to the id property

```js
var arrObj1 = [{
    "id": "1",
    "value": 21,
    "value1": 13
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "value": 21,
    "value1": 13
  },
];

var arrObj2 = [{
    "id": "1",
    "value3": 21,
    "value14": 13
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "value3": 21,
    "value4": 13
  },
];

var arrObj3 = [{
    "id": "1",
    "value5": 21,
    "value6": 13
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "value5": 21,
    "value6": 13
  },
];


const input = [];
input.push(arrObj2, arrObj3);
const preResult = input.flat();
result = preResult.reduce((acc, x) => {
  const index = acc.findIndex(y => y.id === x.id)
  if (index >= 0) {
    acc[index] = {
      ...acc[index],
      ...x
    }

  } else {
    acc.push(x)
  }
  return acc;
}, arrObj1)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for concated arrays

```js
const arrObj1 = [
    { id: '1', value: 21, value1: 13 },
    { id: '2', value: 21, value1: 13 },
];
const arrObj2 = [
    { id: '1', value3: 21, value14: 13 },
    { id: '2', value3: 21, value4: 13 },
];
const arrObj3 = [
    { id: '1', value5: 21, value6: 13 },
    { id: '2', value5: 21, value6: 13 },
];

const result = [...arrObj1, ...arrObj2, ...arrObj3].reduce(
    (acc, { id, ...rest }) => ({ ...acc, [id]: acc[id] ? { ...acc[id], ...rest } : { ...rest } }),
    {},
);

console.log(Object.entries(result).map(([id, data]) => ({ id, ...data })));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over array-length and push here for every entry 1 entry to the result. For getting this entry take a new object with the id and iterate over all (3 or perhaps more) arrays. For every array take the i-th entry and push for every key an entry with key:value (except for the key id itself).

**Remark:** You can use as much arrays you want and every object could contain as much value-prperties as you need. The only restriction is that every array has the same count of objects.

```js
var arrObj1  = [
    {"id":"1","value":21, "value1":13},
    {"id":"2","value":21, "value1":13 }
    ]; 

var arrObj2 = [
    {"id":"1","value3":21, "value4":13},
    {"id":"2","value3":21, "value4":13 }
    ]; 

var arrObj3 = [
    {"id":"1","value5":21, "value6":13},
    {"id":"2","value5":21, "value6":13 }
    ]; 
    
let result =[];
let arrayAll = [arrObj1, arrObj2, arrObj3];

for (let i=0; i<arrayAll[0].length; i++) {

  let obj = arrayAll[0][i];
  let res = { id: obj.id};

  
  for (let j=0; j<arrayAll.length; j++) {
      let obj = arrayAll[j][i];
      Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
          if (key!='id') res[key] = obj[key];
      })
  }
  result.push(res);
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using id to merge multiple objects, Map is one of the good option to merge.

```js
let arrObj1  = [
    {"id":"1","value":21, "value1":13},
    {"id":"2","value":21, "value1":13 },
    ]; 

let arrObj2 = [
    {"id":"1","value3":21, "value14":13},
    {"id":"2","value3":21, "value4":13 },
    ]; 

let arrObj3 = [
    {"id":"1","value5":21, "value6":13},
    {"id":"2","value5":21, "value6":13 },
    ]; 

let mergedArray = [...arrObj1,...arrObj2,...arrObj3].reduce((acc,curr) =>{
    if(acc.has(curr.id)){
      acc.set(curr.id,  {...acc.get(curr.id),...curr});
    }else{
    acc.set(curr.id,curr);
    }
  return acc;
},new Map())
console.log(Array.from(mergedArray,x=>x[1]));
```